# Shell command to rename files with ? inside name

Tags: shell, rename

Environment: CentOS, shell

I have a few files under a directory with the names like

```
B?orn.txt
F?ord.xml
etc
```

How to find/rename all files under the directory containing `?` and delete this `?` in the filenames to make all them like:

```
Born.txt
Ford.xml
etc
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `rename` utillity installed, just use that command:

```
$ rename -n 's/\?//' dir/*
dir/f?ile renamed as dir/file
dir/f?ile2 renamed as dir/file2
dir/f?ile3 renamed as dir/file3
```

The `-n` flag is to check what the utillity would do, remove it to do the rename.

Comment: rename utility installed because rename -v answers in shell "call: rename from to files..." - but when I try rename -n 's/\?//' /var/www/html/dba/* - nothing happens...

Comment: Looks like you have a different version with different syntax.

Comment: well...and what to do to have a "right version" with "right syntax" ?

Comment: @Serge rename is just a small perl script, here: http://pastebin.com/PSXQu39G, make it executable. Of course perl has to be installed.

Comment: @chaos thank you very much - I just copied this script and run it like /var/www/html/rename -n 's/\?//' /var/www/html/dba/* - everything works ! Have a nice day !